# Looping with Ruby in Slim, Sinatra

Tags: ruby, loops, slim-lang

I am trying to make a list of items using Ruby in Slim where each time you add another item it prints the entire list.

The making an array is working, I can get Slim to print the count of the array. I can also print the most recent title and author that will go on my list. (The code is below).

```
= postNum = $blog_posts.length.times do |post|
= params[:title] + ", " + params[:author]
```

What I can't get working is the loop. I am getting all sorts of errors in Sinatra when I try to run the app. The pseudocode for this would be something like: while postNum is greater than 0, print the title and author, count backwards one.

I am new to Ruby and even newer to Slim. How do I get such a basic loop working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Slim but if you want to loop through and object postNum here is what you should do:

```
while postNum.length > 0
 params[:title] + "," + params[author]
end
```

after a quick look at Slim I assume the proper syntax would be:

```
 - while postNum.length > 0
     | #{params[:title]}, #{params[author]}
```

Comment: This part is working, but I am still getting an error when I count one backwards. I've tried $blog_posts.length - 1 and $blog_posts.length -= 1.

Comment: Sure. $blog_posts.length - 1 do (Sorry in comments I'm not sure how to format the code). The error: "Slim::Parser::SyntaxError at /create/post
Unknown line indicator lib/app.rb, Line 20, Column 4 $blog_posts.length - 1 do ^ ".

Comment: That mean that you are not conforming to the right Slim syntax. Review the  Slim [Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim).